# Styling elements based on sibling count in LESS

Tags: less

I have this Less mixin (courtesy of Lea Verou):
I would like to pass a variable of max-items (8) and based on this create the rule set below with a loop. So I don't have to repeat code for every number of child elements (1,2,3,4,...).

```
.list-elements-count-undefined-width() {
  /* one item */
  &:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
  }

  /* two items */
  &:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
  &:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ li {
    width: 50%;
  }

  /* three items */
  &:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
  &:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ li {
    width: (100% / 3);
  }

  /* four items */
  &:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
  &:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ li {
    width: 25%;
  }

  /* five items */
  &:first-child:nth-last-child(5),
  &:first-child:nth-last-child(5) ~ li {
    width: 20%;
  }

  /* six items */
  &:first-child:nth-last-child(6),
  &:first-child:nth-last-child(6) ~ li {
    width: (100% / 6);
  }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't `&:first-child { width: 100% / @numberOfItems}` work for all of them?

Comment: No. Number of child elements can be anything. We don't know in advance how many child elements will be generated in markup.

Comment: @Blix: Less has no idea of how many elements would be present in your markup. You would either have to pass a max expected number statically during compilation (or) use compilation on Client side which is strictly not recommended even by the Less website.

Comment: Ok, lets say the max expected number is 8.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? It's not a big deal for us to [write](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/400574a0439220196634) code for you, but it's not what the SO is for. (Just read [Loops](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) and adapt it for your snippet).

Answer (score 3):

```
.list-elements-count-undefined-width(@i) when (@i > 0) {
  .list-elements-count-undefined-width((@i - 1));
  &:first-child:nth-last-child(@{i}),
  &:first-child:nth-last-child(@{i}) ~ li{
    width: (100% / @i);
  }
}
.list-elements-count-undefined-width(8);
```